# UTM Parameter able to track for other pages besides landing page?

Tags: google-analytics, utm

here's a question for UTM Parameter.
I am confused that whether I can still track where the user come from after they click the UTM code reach to the landing and then to the secondary or other pages.
Or the UTM Parameter just work on the landing page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user lands to your site through a utm-tagged link then Google Analytics will assign the traffic source information for that visit such as source, medium, keyword etc based on utm values. traffic source information is stored in a session level dimensions so these will be the same for all the pageviews, events and transactions in a given session

- here is the description of [how traffic sources are processed](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205762?hl=en)
- and here is the description of [dimension scopes](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033861?hl=en)

Comment: Yes, I have read all these before, but I am still quite confused. So if let's say the user went to the third page after they come in using UTM link, am I able to track the traffic on Google Analytics, Third Page > Source/Medium?

Comment: if the user come came to the site with link utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=promo and viewed three pages then in pages report all the three pages will have a source `facebook` and medium `promo`

Comment: @demoncoder It helps to keep in mind that traffic channel is a property of the session, not of a specific page (that's by definition, really, as a change in attribution ends the current session and starts a new one).